# Returning Value from HTML window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that opens a pop up window:

```
   function popUp(url) 
{ leftPos = 0
 topPos = 0
 if (screen) {
 leftPos = (screen.width / 2) - 150
 topPos = (screen.height / 2) - 250
 } 
 newWindow=window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=500,left='+leftPos+',top='+topPos);
 if (window.focus) {newWindow.focus()}
```

when the user closes this window I need to fire this code:

```
Javascript:document.quoteform.submit()
```

Can anyone give me a simple solution to return a boolean from the popup when closed to be able to fire my JS. Any help is appreciated I'm having a brain fart today I know this should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the window that opens current through [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)
So you can do `window.opener.document.quoteform.submit()` from new window;

Answer (score 0):

The window object has a property `window.closed` when when the popup window closes, is set to `true`. You can use that to determine if the window was closed. More on window.closed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.closed)

Using this property and the fact that popups can access the window that opened them, you can devise a mechanism to communicate to the parent window via popup when to check for this property.

e.g.

Popup window's `onunload` can be used to pass on a message to opening window to check if the window was closed.

Note that onunload will be called even if the popup window page is refereshed. You don't want to use that as a means for submitting the form, because the window will not be closed.